# Can I echo php value into form?

Tags: php

Is it possible to echo php value into form label? Currently I can only echo into textbox which is editable for the user but I want it to be unable to edit like label, any way I can do so?

Below is for textbox which is able to work

```
 <input style="color:#000000" type="text" value="<?php echo $account['Username']; ?>" name="name" required/>
```

I tried to echo in label but nothing shown in my web

```
 <label for="fullname"><?php echo $account['Fullname']; ?></label>
```

Comment: sure the same way you echo anything else. did you try?

Comment: Are you saying you want the text to be inside the input, but not editable? The HTML5 `placeholder` attribute may be what you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: **what** do you want to echo into the form label? The answer is YES, but we'd need clarification on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JasonKennaly I don't want to change the value of what's being echo from mySQL

Answer (score 1):

Use the echo statement. Like this:

```
<label><?php echo ("this is a label");?></label>
```

Comment: What's your problem with this solution, it's the best solution you may get for your question.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this either. The question is ambiguous, but this is a pretty direct answer.

Comment: Your code is only able to work if it's self type "this is a label" but it won't work if I try to echo from mySQL <?php echo $account['Fullname']; ?>

Comment: PHP doesn't care whether it's a constant or a variable. More likely the issue is that `$account['Fullname']` is not getting retrieved from the database properly.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

You can use the echo function like you used it before.

Make sure:

1. you are using PHP file (*.php)
2. index in array is not empty
3. you are using < ? php tags

Try this:

```
// index.php
<?php
$text = "privet";
?>

<label for="fullname"><?php echo $text; ?></label>
// output is <label for="fullname">privet</label>
```

4. read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php
5. be careful and read also this http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

BTW: if it still does not working... just use dump to get the variable info

```
<label><?php echo $var; ?></label> // does not working
// ok -> then dump the var!
<?php var_dump($var); ?> // hmm.. lets see (maybe null or string(0)?) :-)
```